# Are other HTTP methods necessary?

Tags: http, post, get

I've been trying to find a simple (or heck even a complex answer to this), so I hope someone can shed some light on a curiosity I've got about http requests.

I'm building a web service and will be making HTTP requests to get and update information.

I've built a few things like this in the past so I'm familiar with GET, and POST; but I came across a few other methods like PUT, and DELETE and not many pages have information on them, to me they seem like the POST method just with a different name.

So my question(s) is:
1) Is it really necessary to use PUT, DELETE or is POST still just as useful?
2) If they are (or aren't necessary) then what makes them necessary i.e. when would they be used/preferred over POST?

Comment: 1.- You can use PUT, DELETE if your Web Service is restful, is your service is SOAP you only use POST and GET.
2.-  Depends on your web service SOAP or REST.

Comment: POST is sufficient for any API you build yourself.  Some tools might want to force you to use the other 3 but that's the tool's limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to design your URLs. If I'm implementing a REST API, I like to use REST URLs for "nouns" (entities) of my application, and use the various HTTP methods as different "verbs" to act on those entities.

Usually I use them as following:

POST : to create a new record
GET : to retrieve one or more records
PUT : to update a record
DELETE : to delete a record

For example, see this article about more information about REST API design.
https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9

Comment: Awesome!  thanks that link is pretty much what I was looking for :)